# Set WPF Binding.StringFormat Property on TextBox via Style

Tags: wpf, data-binding, wpf-style

I have an WPF application contains many `TextBox`es having different kind of Bindings which all share the same `StringFormat` property (its a technical application, the Textboxes should display values with units "xxx mm"...)

I want to set up the Binding in the XAML/Designer, but I'd like to avoid setting the TextFormat property on every individual Binding. Is there a way to do this using Styles?

If I try to set the Binding in a `Setter` for the Text property like

```
    <Style x:Name="mmtext" TargetType="TextBox" x:Key="mmtext">
        <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding Path=A,StringFormat={}{0} mm}" />
    </Style>
```

I need to provide a `Path` in the Setters Value property, and I cannot define any binding in the XAML itself (as this would override the value set in the Style).

Is there a way to set/modify only the `StringFormat` property in a single Binding (i.e. the Binding for the `Text` property) using a Style?

Or do I need to look for templating or a custom control?

Comment: I'm not aware of a style-based solution. What about a converter? You'll still have to specify the converter in each control's binding of course, so you aren't reducing the amount of XAML you write, but at least the *formatting logic* is in one place, if you ever need to change it across the entire application.

Answer (score 7):

you could probably bind the DataContext of the textbox rather than the text property

```
 <TextBox DataContext="{Binding Path=A}" />
```

and then use a setter like

```
<Style x:Name="mmtext" TargetType="TextBox" x:Key="mmtext">
    <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding Path=., StringFormat={}{0} mm}" />
</Style>
```

for a TwoWay binding you will need a converter anyways to get rid of the extra mms